# separating and extracting part of strings of URLs using regex?

Tags: python, regex, text, nlp

I have a `df` with variable named `url`. Each url string in `url` has a unique six character alphanumeric ID in the URL string. Ive been trying to extract a specific part of each string, the `article_id` from all urls, and then add it to the `df` as a new variable.

For example, `xwpd7w` is the `article_id` for `https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/xwpd7w/how-a-brooklyn-gang-may-have-gotten-crazy-rich-dealing-for-el-chapo`

How do I extract `article_ids` from all urls in the df based on their position next to `/article/`? Using any method, regex or not?

I have so far done the following:

```
df.url.str.split()

ex output: [https://www.vice.com/en_au/article/j539yy/smo...
```

```
df['cutcurls'] = df.url.str.join(sep=' ')
ex output: h t t p s : / / w w w . v i c e . c o m / e n
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the "str.extract" method.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({"url":["https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/xwpd7w/how-a-brooklyn-gang-may-have-gotten-crazy-rich-dealing-for-el-chapo","https://www.www.www//en_us/article/idId2019/buzzwords"]}) 

df["articel_id"]= df.url.str.extract(r"/article/([^/]+)")

    Out:
        url articel_id
        0  https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/xwpd7w/how-...     xwpd7w
        1  https://www.www.www//en_us/article/idId2019/bu...   idId2019
```

([^/]+): groups consecutive non '/' characters